# Braided stainless water line to boiler expansion tank?

Tags: plumbing, boiler

My boiler expansion tank (Amtrol EX-30) hangs on a 1/2” type L copper pipe suspended from a 1/2" copper tee. The bottom of the tank (the air valve) is within an inch of the floor, which makes it impossible to check the bladder pressure without dismounting the tank. The tank can’t be raised a useful amount because of other nearby pipes. The best solution would be to relocate the tank, but I’m thinking that if I shorten the pipe and then connect to the tank through a braided stainless water line such as the kind used to connect dishwashers, I can make a ring-shaped cradle for the tank and let it sit on the floor. Then to check air pressure, or to check for excess weight from a bladder failure, just pick up the tank while still attached to the braided water line.

There’s no foot traffic in the boiler room and nothing would disturb the tank in its cradle. Heating system pressure is 12-15 PSI and the tank doesn’t get hot. There’s no glycol or any additives in the boiler water. The line would not support the tank's weight at all.

Is there any good reason not to use a braided stainless water line about 2 feet long?

Comment: Braided line will be ok if it is listed for use with hot water or temps in the range of your boiler.

Comment: It is a little misleading to call one of these a braided stainless steel line.  These are elastomer lines with braded stainless armoring for protection against abrasion and maybe against rodents.